# How to open a directory/folder and a URL through Terminal

Tags: command-line

I can navigate my files quite fast through terminal. Faster than double clicking... open... look, double click... etc.

How do I open a directory in the Ubuntu GUI? For example:

```
cd projects
{some cmd} client_project
```

Then voila, it opens in the Ubuntu GUI as if i navigated manually?

Also, how can I open a URL in my default browser via terminal. It'd be awesome to go:     <kbd>F12</kbd>

```
open http://google.com
```

And Chrome opens it up.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**To Open Directory:**

- To open a Folder from terminal type the following,

  ```
  nautilus /path/to/that/folder
  ```

  or

  ```
  xdg-open /path/to/the/folder
  ```

  i.e

  ```
  nautilus /home/karthick/Music
  xdg-open /home/karthick/Music
  ```
- Simply typing nautilus will take you file browser,

  ```
  nautilus
  ```

**To Open URL:**

- You can type any one of the following in terminal,

  ```
  xdg-open http://google.com       
  google-chrome http://google.com                 
  opera http://google.com
  firefox http://google.com
  ```
- If you want to open two URL's at the same time then leave some space after the first URL and type the second,

  ```
  firefox www.google.com www.gmail.com
  ```

**Note:**

- Linux is case-sensitive, so type the file name correctly.
- You can also add an alias to short the command,for example if you need `openurl` instead of `x-www-browser` you should edit the .bashrc file
  `gedit ~/.bashrc`
- In the bottom of the file add the following lines

  ```
  alias openurl=x-www-browser
  ```

  [image]
- Save and close the file.
- Now you can open URLs by typing,

  ```
  openurl http://google.com
  ```

Comment: xdg-open works for directrories and other files, too

Comment: @FlorianDiesch forgot to include that,thanks for remembering :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out more gernerally that `xdg-open` should have the same result as clicking on any file in a folder or on your desktop. It should open your file/folder/url with the default application to handle that file type. I have it aliased as `go` in my `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I installed Komodo and it set up `komodo somefile.html` to open files but i didn't see it in the bashrc file. Where else could it be *and* could I change it to `edit somefile.html` but opens in Komodo as if i typed komodo?

Comment: Well, there's already a `/usr/bin/edit`, so I'd choose something else, but anyways... In `~/.bashrc` add a line that says `alias edit='komodo'`

Comment: Everything worked fine, except, the openurl thing runs chrome in the terminal as well as the GUI. If i close temrinal it shuts off Chrome? Whys that?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of typing all the quotes etc. one could use:

```
nautilus .
```

Works with directories containing spaces in their names.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the aplication. Both Nautilus and Chrome accept path (url) as parameter.

`nautilus /directory/subdirectory/subsubdirectory`

or

`cd /directory/subdirectory/subsubdirectory` and then `nautilus .` (the dot is important -- it says to Nautilus to open the current directory)

`google-chrome www.google.com`

or

`x-www-browser www.google.com` -- this command calls the browser set as default (so if your default browser is Chrome, it will open Chrome)

Comment: how would one add a shorter command that does x-www-browser? i.e. `openurl www.google.com`?

Comment: You can create an alias. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29 Just add `alias open="x-www-browser"` to `~/.bashrc` file

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the above answers are OK, but this is what I think you are looking for:

```
nautilus "$(pwd)"

xdg-open "$(pwd)"
```

I was just experimenting today, and it worked. Isn't it fabulous?

Answer (score 1):

#### Open Directory:

- To open a Directory or Folder from terminal.

  ```
  nautilus /home/user/path_to_folder/ &
  ```

  Or

  ```
  xdg-open /home/user/path_to_folder/ &
  ```

  The ampersand `&` is used; so the process get start into the background and we can continue to use the shell or terminal without waiting  for script to get finished.

  **Note:** For better result use absolute path.

#### Open URL

- Type any one of the following in terminal.

  ```
  opera http://www.google.com &
  firefox http://www.google.com &
  xdg-open http://www.google.com &
  ```

#### To close directory, URL, etc.:

- Onto the Folder/URL or any screen window, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

**To open a directory/ folder**

You can use, `nautilus .` and press enter to open the **current directory**.

To open **path specified location** try the following.

E.g. If you want to open Music folder under this location:

```
/media/dulithdecozta/A08A64BB8A648F98/Music/
```

Then execute the following.

```
nautilus /media/dulithdecozta/A08A64BB8A648F98/Music/
```

**To open a URL via the terminal**

E.g. Lets open **stackoverflow.com** via **terminal**

(Google Chrome)

```
google-chrome http://stackoverflow.com
```

(Firefox)

```
firefox http://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to paste the url file in the address box of Firefox, at least, haven't tried other browsers, and when you hit enter Firefox shows the real address of the url.  Paste that in the address box.    Works for me