# How to open a file manager of the current directory in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, window, filemanager

When I work in terminal, sometimes I want to open the current directory in a GUI file manager.
And then to click the items in the window to run the application. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think this question is an exact duplicate. There are [many similar questions](http://askubuntu.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=xdg-open) with some identical answers but none of the questions have the exact same focus as this question. The closest question is [How to open a directory/folder and a URL through Terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/17062/667)

Comment: Tried all the answers below. The ones that worked on Ubuntu 20.04 are: `xdg-open .`, `nautilus .`, `browse .`. But `gnome-open .` did not work as-is (I guess either gnome is not installed or there's some other reason for that). Nonethless, this is to confirm what worked as of 01-Feb-2022.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

The following works in all desktop environments by using the default file manager:

```
xdg-open .
```

You can also open files from the terminal as if you had double clicked them in the file manager:

```
xdg-open file
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu 16

Comment: Works in CentOS 6.10 as well.

Comment: @TheGodfather it works it Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: for ubuntu, uses: `caja`, or `nautilus`

Comment: Works like a charm in Ubuntu 18. :) Thanks for this!

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This shows a deprecation warning, the newer command is `gio open .` (Centos 7)

Comment: Is there a similar command to "Choose a file"? e.g. It will open the default file manager and you can choose/select a file and it'll return the file's absolute path? More like a "File-picker"?

Answer (score 53):

**Problem**

This tip will explain How to open a file manager of the current directory in the terminal

**Solution 1**

The following works in all desktop environments by using the default file manager:

```
xdg-open .
```

**Solution 2**

You can also open files from the terminal as if you had double clicked them in the file manager:

```
xdg-open file
```

**Solution 3**

If you are using Gnome, you can use the gnome-open command, like so:

```
gnome-open .
```

**Solution 4**

You can use nautilus [path]. for current directory -

```
nautilus .
```

Comment: This is the most complete one and should be the answer. Works in RedHat 7.2 x64.

Answer (score 42):

You write nautilus [path]. for current directory -

```
nautilus .
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that you have to keep terminal window alive while you are navigating. If you kill the window, the file explorer gets killed too.

Comment: This is easily solved by adding `&` to the end like this: `nautilus . &`

Comment: This is easier to remember for me.

Answer (score 12):

In Ubuntu 20.04, you can just say `browse .` to open the current directory

Comment: `browse` is just a symlink to `xdg-open`. So you can use both of them in the same way. (i.e you can also open files with `browse`)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using GNOME, you can use the [`gnome-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gnome-open.1.html) command, like so:

```
gnome-open .
```

Comment: To use it first install:  sudo apt install libgnome2-bin

Comment: I wonder why isn't there common command for opening whatever the GUI is. I have tried all commands from above answers and no one worked for me. This is the only working on Ubuntu

Comment: Is there a way to open gnome as sudo? I tried `sudo gnome-open .` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `nautilus .` and press enter to open the **current directory**.

To open **path specified location** try the following.

E.g. If you want to open Music folder under this location:

```
/media/dulithdecozta/A08A64BB8A648F98/Music/
```

Then execute the following.

```
nautilus /media/dulithdecozta/A08A64BB8A648F98/Music/
```