# How do I open file manager from terminal in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: filemanager

In Ubuntu 16.04 I can run `open .` to open file manager from terminal. The same command does not work in Ubuntu 18.04. How do I open file manager from current dir in terminal in 18.04?

Comment: If you want to use `nautilus` you can just type its name (or the start of it and hit <tab>).  If you use `thunar` type its name. etc

Comment: `open` doesn't work for me on 16.04. Did you mean `xdg-open .`?

Comment: Also, have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/31069/367990

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you use `nautilus` you need to type

```
nautilus
```

You can of course provide it with the directory you want, eg. `nautilus /usr/share/wallpapers`.  If you prefer other file managers, for example `thunar` just use the command `thunar` instead.